# C++ template class confusion

Tags: c++, templates

So i am a fairly experienced C programmer who recently took a dive into C++ for a toy-compiler I am writing. I am currently "modernizing" my C++ code because my current code looks more like ANSI-C and the only C++ thing it takes advantage of is std::vector.

So I decided to use iterators instead of manually iterating through containers and arrays via a for loop with a count variable. I noticed that I need to get to the middle of several iterators fairly often so I wrote a static class with a function that does that.

Now I am extending this function to not only return an iterator to the middle element but return a vector of iterators to several parts of the container. I am using templates to make the code more generic, however I am kind of stuck with the implementation of my current function.

Here is the definition of the class:

```
namespace dbc {
  template<typename generic_iterator_t>
  class itertools {
  public:
    /* returns an iterator which points to the middle element,
     * the same as calling get_fraction_iterator with fraction = 2 */
    static generic_iterator_t get_middle_iterator(
      generic_iterator_t begin, generic_iterator_t end
    );

    /* splits a container into several chunks and returns
     * the iterators in a vector */
    template<typename generic_iterator_t, size_t chunks>
    static std::vector<generic_iterator_t> get_chunk_iterator(
      generic_iterator_t begin, generic_iterator_t end
    );

    /* calculates the optimal chunk size, particulary useful
     * for get_chunk_iterator */
    template<typename generic_number_t>
    static constexpr generic_number_t
    get_optimal_chunk_size(generic_number_t val);
  };
}
```

How do I implement this function?
As far as I know this should be correct but it isn't.

```
template<typename generic_iterator_t, size_t chunks>
static std::vector<generic_iterator_t>
dbc::itertools<generic_iterator_t>::get_chunk_iterator<
  generic_iterator_t, size_t
>(generic_iterator_t begin, generic_iterator_t end)
```

Comment: btw: dbc is the namespace

Comment: You should try to add more line breaks to shorten the lines (it's not super readable). Also, you repeated the `template<class generic_iterator_t>` for the methods whereas it's not needed (Edit: I mean, that will work, but the class' `generic_iterator_t` will be shadowed by the method's).  Otherwise, since both your class and method are templates, you need two template parameter lists: see this [example](http://ideone.com/3p1uGX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
template<typename generic_iterator_t, size_t chunks>
static std::vector<generic_iterator_t> get_chunk_iterator(
```

to

```
template<size_t chunks>
static std::vector<generic_iterator_t> get_chunk_iterator(
```

and

```
template<typename generic_iterator_t, size_t chunks>
static std::vector<generic_iterator_t>
dbc::itertools<generic_iterator_t>::get_chunk_iterator<
  generic_iterator_t, size_t
>(generic_iterator_t begin, generic_iterator_t end)
```

to

```
template<typename generic_iterator_t>
template<size_t chunks> 
std::vector<generic_iterator_t> 
dbc::itertools<generic_iterator_t>::get_chunk_iterator(
  generic_iterator_t begin, generic_iterator_t end
){
  return {};
}
```

there is no need to repeat the type `generic_iterator_t` in both the class, and in a static method of a class.

Finally, your style of using a template class as a kind of template namespace is awkward and probably doesn't yield much good.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work, but maybe thats not your fault but visual studios fault. Which compiler are you using?